# Loop a SQL query row by row on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
time1                              val1     val2    time2
2021-01-20 07:32:39.169390+01:00   john     dale    2021-01-20 15:39:47.429788+01:00
2021-01-20 20:39:18.485783+01:00   anne     mckay   2021-01-20 20:40:17.176882+01:00
2021-01-20 20:45:19.155543+01:00   john     dale    2021-01-20 20:40:17.176882+01:00
```

And I have a postgres function that given as inputs 'time1', 'val1', 'val2' and 'time2' returns some of the inputs plus two additional columns: 'val3' and 'val4'.

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.function('val1', 'val2', 'time1', 'time2')
```

And would return:

```
   val1     val2    val3  val4    
   john     dale    28    80
   anne     mckay   45    90
   john     dale    65    110
```

My question is: how can I run that function row by row (or in another way, but taking into account the different row values as inputs) and merge the result with the original df, so to have this df as result?

```
time1                              val1     val2    time2                             val3  val4
2021-01-20 07:32:39.169390+01:00   john     dale    2021-01-20 15:39:47.429788+01:00  28    80
2021-01-20 20:39:18.485783+01:00   anne     mckay   2021-01-20 20:40:17.176882+01:00  45    90
2021-01-20 20:45:19.155543+01:00   john     dale    2021-01-20 20:40:17.176882+01:00  65    110
```

What I tried to do so far is to create a function that retrieve the query with f-strings taking the 4 inputs, something like this:

```
def retrieve_val3_val4(time1, val1, val2, time2):
    query = f'''
            SELECT *
            FROM schema.function('{val1}', '{val2}', '{time1}', '{time2}')
            '''
    df = pd.read_sql(query)
    return df
```

And then tried to apply the function to the df like this:

```
df.apply(lambda row: retrieve_val3_val4(row.val1, row.val2, row.time1, row.time2), axis=1)
```

But this returns an object type and not a df.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a lateral join.  Assuming the original row is stored in a table, then you can use:

```
select t.*, f.val3, f.val4
from t cross join lateral
     schema.function(t.val1, t.val2, t.time1, t.time2) f;
```

You can also use `values` to construct the values on the fly:

```
select t.*, f.val3, f.val4
from (values (?, ?, ?, ?)
     ) v(val1, val2, time1, time2) cross join lateral
     schema.function(v.val1, v.val2, v.time1, v.time2) f;
```

Comment: Thanks, but here is where I have a problem, because the original df is not stored in a table so I cannot easily do the cross join lateral. In my situation I need to start working from the pandas df

Comment: Tatsuya . . . Your question is tagged Postgres.  This is a Postgres solution.  If the data is in an application, you can use the second option to pass data into the query.